# Spring Data with mongodb - how can I access dynamic fields in a document?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

So I'm trying to use Spring Data with mongodb without providing a strict schema, I have let's say document 'person':

```
{
 '_id':'1234',
 'name':'John Doe',
 'address':'Texas'
}
```

So I created a java bean:

```
@Document(collection='people')
class Person {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String address;
  //all getters and setters
}
```

But on the same hierarchy level in a document I could have different dynamic fields like: hobbies, friends etc.

How can I create a java bean document object to access those dynamic fields in a hash-like manner while using MongoRepository support?

Comment: Are you asking for support for *dynamic* schemas? (see [mongo site](https://www.mongodb.com/scale/dynamic-schema-design))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `Override default mapping with custom converters` and do the  `Saving using a registered Spring Converter` and `Reading using a Spring Converter` as described in [documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters)